# How to import an Kafka operator in an existing IBM splmm code?

Tags: import, apache-kafka, operator-keyword

I have created a Kafka Operator using ibm spl code. Now I have to replace the input of an existing ibm splmm code with this kafka operator. Currently the code receives the input from a different location, and now I would like to change the input as the kafka consumer. Help me out with this issue. Thanks.

Comment: It would really help us to answer your question if you included some sample of the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that. So,I created a Kafka Operator which receives an input message from the python code and writes it on a text file.
Composite Kafka_Read_OP {
        param
                expression $topic : "DNS_EXT" ;
    graph

```
            stream<rstring message> KafkaStream = KafkaConsumer()
            {
                    param
                            propertiesFile : getThisToolkitDir() + "/etc/consumer.properties" ;
                            topic : $topic;
            }

           () as Sink = FileSink(KafkaStream)
              {
                 param
                   file : "/tmp/output.txt";
                   format : txt;
                   append : true;
                   flush : 1u;
               } //End of FileSink.
```

And I have an IBM spl code which recieves an input from another spl code that looks like,.

public composite ExternalDNSImportSubscriptionWrapper(output ImportSubStream)
 {
           param
                  expression $subscription : getSubmissionTimeValue("externalFeeder::subscription", getCompileTimeValue("externalFeeder::subscription","kind == \"\""));
                type $outputType;
        graph
                stream ImportSubStream = Import()
 {
                        param
                                applicationScope : "com.zel.streams.cti" ;
                            subscription : kind == "EnrichmentData" && category == "ExternalDNSzel" && id == getChannel();
                            //subscription : kind == "EnrichmentData" && category == "ExternalDNSzel" && id == 0;
                }

Now I need to replace the above code with the Kafka Operator I created. 
So do I have to send the output of the Kafka to Import or
Just delete this whole import code and create a Kafka here. If I do so I need to change the import in other connecting codes.
I am not able to find any examples to send an output from kafka to an import.